# custom taxonomy in wordpress custom post type not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I used [wp-types](http://wp-types.com/) types plugin to create custom post type and custom taxonomy. I got custom fields value in template file with types API successfully but taxonomy not showing and I didn't found any useful API for that.

Please guide me to how show custom taxonomy in custom post type.

thanks for your attentions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer add this to template file:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'custom-taxonomy-name', '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="tag-links">', '', '</span></footer>' ); ?>
```